# Dynamic Watermark / On-the-fly Zip Files problem

Tags: php

Before I start, I can post up some code later. I'm in work just now but the problem's really bugging me! Hopefully I can explain it well enough.

I have two functions which work as expected on their own. One of them is displaying a watermark over my photographs. Because my client is fussy and changes things every other day, I decided to dynamically add the watermark when the image is requested.

It works by using my .htaccess file to redirect any requests made to my image directory to go through a watermark.php file. In this file (code to follow), the function picks up the requested image, applies the watermark and then outputs the result and alters the page headers to correspond with that file type.

This works as it should and I'm happy with that.

My other function is creating zip files on-the-fly of specific images (from an array) from this folder. The problem is that because the zip function doesn't go through my watermark.php file, the compressed images don't have the watermark attached.

Hopefully that makes sense. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? The only thing I've tried is updating the array URLs to go to watermark.php?src=image.jpg to see if that would work (instead of going direct to the image) but the resulting zip file was empty.

Any help / suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your watermarking code as a function in separate file and include it in watermark.php and in whateverZIPsIt.php . So you can apply that function to requested images in both places without duplication of your code.

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea, thanks! I'll let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to actually store the watermarked versions of the images somewhere on disk, with the ability to regenerate them based on a new watermark using the original images.

This might be faster in the end, as the watermarked image wouldn't have to be created on every single request.